# Improve MyEclipse's clean and build performance

Tags: myeclipse

MyEclipse Enterprise Workbench

Version: 10.7.1
Build id: 10.7.1-20130201

This is what myeclipse.ini has,

```
-vmargs
-Xmx2048m
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=256m
-Dosgi.nls.warnings=ignore
```

I have Windows 7 (64 bit) with 8GB RAM. 
Clean + Build takes 4.15 minutes and then building a WAR takes about 2.22 minutes. That's over 6 and half minutes. This is development machine and I need it to be fast. I upload a new build everyday and sometimes twice a day.

What areas I can look into? Assigning more memory to eclipse?

Thank you